# MATLAB: meshgrid pairs whoe sums<=1

Tags: matlab

I need some help with MATLAB coding. I have two variables x=0:0.1:1 and y=0:0.1:1. I want to generate the meshgrid only for those points which satisfy the condition x+y<=1. Please help me.

Comment: So what values should the grids store for x+y>1? Zeros?

Answer (score 0):

`[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y)`  returns two matrixes, representing points from (0,0) to (1,1).  The requirement to remove values where x + y >= 1 works well on a graph - basically just draw a diagonal line, creating a triangle. However, it doesn't work very well for matrices - who's ever heard of a triangle matrix?

What you can do is set the excluded values to some 'bad' value, and then ignore them.  I chose to set them to NaN, because functions like surf won't plot nan's:

```
x = 0:.1:1;
y = 0:.1:1;
[X,Y] = surf(x,y);
X(X+Y>=1) = nan;
Y(X+Y>=1) = nan;

surf(X,Y,X.*Y)
```